# Load Services based on other bundles, Symfony2 DI

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

In my `Extension` class I want to load some services only if some other bundle is installed.
however since the `ContainerBuilder` passed to the load method is a temporary empty one, I can not use methods such as `$container->hasExtension("foo_bar")` how can I achieve this?

Comment: Compiler passes: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html

Comment: I don't see the point, in your `Extension` you don't *load* services, you just *define* them, they will be loaded when first called

Comment: @Cerad that's what my current implementation, wanted to know if there is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All bundles are in the `kernel.bundles` parameter. Use that to check if one is available. For instance:

```
public function load(ContainerBuilder $container, array $configs)
{
    $bundles = $container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');
    if (isset($bundles['AcmeDemoBundle'])) {
        // ...
    }

    /* or
    if (in_array('Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle', $bundles)) {
        // ...
    }
    */
}
```

If you want to tweak other bundle's services or you need to read all other services, you'll want to use a Compiler Pass.